# Programmatic access to fslex and fsyacc

Tags: f#

The fslex and fsyacc tools currently require 2-stage compilation, generating files that are then compiled by fsc. It seems to me that these tools would be much easier to use if the source files were embedded resources, fed to fslex and fsyacc programmatically and the generated code compiled on-the-fly using the CodeDom.

Is this feasible and, if so, what would be required to implement this?

Answer (score 4):

Jon, this is a great question; in fact, one of the design goals I have for [fsharp-tools](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-tools) (new lexer- and parser-generator implementations for F#) is for them to be embeddable, specifically to enable scenarios like this.

As of now, I haven't implemented (yet) the functionality which would let you do this *easily* in *fsharplex*, but don't let that deter you; I've written *fsharplex* (and the other tools in *fsharp-tools*) in a more-or-less purely-functional style, so there shouldn't be any issues with global state or anything like that. It should be relatively straightforward to hack up the compiler code so you can build a regex AST using some combinators, run the compiler to get a compiled DFA, then emit IL for your state machine into a dynamic assembly (which you could then "bake" and execute).

*fsharpyacc* currently uses an approach where I've put the bulk of the compilation logic into a purely-functional library, *Graham*; the idea there is that the grammar analysis/manipulation and parser DFA compilation algorithms should be generic, reusable, and easy to test, so anyone else wanting to build language tools with F# will have a common framework on which to build them. Likewise, contributions/improvements to *Graham* can easily flow back to *fsharpyacc*. Eventually, I will modify *fsharplex* to use this same approach, which will allow you to embed the regex compiler in your own code simply by referencing the NuGet package (you'd just need to write the code to generate IL from the DFA).

*fsharplex* and *fsharpyacc* use MEF to allow various backends to be plugged in; for now, they're only targetting `fslex` and `fsyacc` for compatibility reasons, but I'd like to implement code-based backends (as opposed to the current table-based backends) to get better performance in the future.

Update -- I just re-read your question and noticed you want to embed the `*.fsl` and `*.fsy` files themselves and invoke the respective compilers at run-time. You could accomplish this by compiling the tools and referencing the assemblies from your own projects. IIRC, I exposed an entry point in both compilers so they could be called from outside code; the main entry points (e.g., what gets executed when you invoke the tools from a console) simply parse the command-line arguments then pass them into this "external" entry point.

There is one problem with directly embedding the `*.fsl` and `*.fsy` files though; if you embed them, then run them through *fsharplex* and *fsharpyacc* at run-time, your user-defined actions (e.g., the code executed when a lexer or parser rule is matched) will still be specified as F# source code -- you'd need to decide how you want to compile them into executable code.

Answer (score 2):

It should be feasible to provide a parser combinator-like interface with a backend that uses expression trees (the LISP "eval" of F#) or something similar, for full integration with the language. Or else a TypeProvider. There are many options. If table generation is an expensive computation, it could be cached by providing a `Cache`, for example a disk cache.

I think nothing except lack of time, dedication and expertise, prevents us from having tools with (non-monadic) parser combinator-like interface, yet efficient compiled implementation.

Sometimes I get back to this pet project of mine, playing with an algebraic approach to optimizing regular expressions (and lexers) specified in source using combinators and then compiled to a state machine. It still lacks a few key pieces for efficiency, but there it is:

https://github.com/toyvo/ocaml-regex-algebraic

Comment: My new implementation of `fslex`, `fsharplex` is also based on *Regular Expression Derivatives, Re-examined`. Code is here if you want to have a look: https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-tools

Comment: "parser combinator-like interface". That is exactly what I *don't* want. I'd like the same easy-to-use DSL but with run-time compilation instead of 2-stage build.

Comment: @JonHarrop compiling the same DSL at runtime sounds entirely pointless. Are you perhaps shopping for a better build tool?

Comment: @toyvo "compiling the same DSL at runtime sounds entirely pointless. Are you perhaps shopping for a better build tool?". I don't think I have the luxury of choosing another build tool but why complicate the build when you can integrate the tools instead?

Comment: @JonHarrop sorry I must be just misunderstanding what you have in mind. Re-reading it again, is this better IDE integration, fewer clicks/actions to use fslex/yacc? That'd help - but that does not have to involve embedded resources or running the tool at runtime.  Could a TypeProvider do it perhaps?